# Delegation pattern in Python using annotation

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, delegation

I have a class that should mimic behaviour of other class but with some flavour. For example Kotlin have delegation pattern (https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/delegation-pattern) as a part of language to do such thing. But for Python when I try code below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Generic, T

@dataclass
class Wrapper(T, Generic[T]):
    __value__: T
   
   def __getattr__(self, item):
       return getattr(self.__value__, item)

   # also need to delegate all magick methods
   def __len__(self):
       return self.__value__.__len__()

   def try_some_funny_things(self):
       setattr(__builtins__, "True", False)


funny_string = Wrapper[str]()
funny_string.  # I want typehints as for str class here
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

What are my final purposes:

1. Make PyCharm/Pylint (other typechecker) show fields/methods hints
2. Do not delegate all magic methods manually to **value** field

Any suggestion how can I do something like this in Python 3?